# In my test class I am trying to cover map.values loop part but I am not able to cover this

Tags: apex, trigger, controller, visual-workflow, salesforce-id

This is my class

```
public class IssuedMaterialHandler {
  //---  Decleration of the objects  ---//
  public boolean diisplayPopUp {get; set;} 
  public Boolean hideButton_Issue{get;set;}
  public Integer totalAmount {get; set;}
  public string massage {get; set;}
  public List<WrapperClass> listWrapper {get;set;}
  public List<New_Job_Material_Issued__c> InsertJMIList = new List<New_Job_Material_Issued__c>(); 
  public Set<Id> RecordId = new Set<Id>();
  public Set<Id> RecordId_Checked = new Set<Id>();
  public Map<Id,Bill_Of_Material__c> BOMMap = new  Map<Id,Bill_Of_Material__c>();
  public List<Bill_Of_Material__c> BOMList {get; set;}
  public Map<Id,Master_Material__c> MMMap = new Map<Id,Master_Material__c>();
  public Map<Id,Master_Material_LineItem__c> MMLIMap = new Map<Id,Master_Material_LineItem__c>();      
  public Map<Id, List<Master_Material_LineItem__c>> MMLIMap_checked= new Map<Id,List<Master_Material_LineItem__c>>(); 
  public List<Master_Material_LineItem__c> MMLIMap_Checkeds = new List<Master_Material_LineItem__c>();
  public static final Id CURRENT_BOM_ID = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
  public static final string BOUGHT_OUT_ITEM           = 'Bought Out Items';
  public static final string RAW_MATERIAL              = 'Raw material';
  public static final string CONSUMABLE_AND_SAMLL_ITEM = 'Consumables and Small items';
  public static final string STATUS_AVALIABLE          = 'Available';
  public static final string STATUS_UNAVALIABLE        = 'Unavailable';
  public static final string LOTS_MATERIAL_ISSUED_SUCCESSFULLY  = 'Lots Material Issued Successfully.';
  public static final string NO_MATERIAL_ISSUED_SUCCESSFULLY  = 'No.Material Issued Successfully.';

  //---  Constructor of the class  ---// 
  public IssuedMaterialHandler(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    Integer Count_CON_RAW = 0;
    BOMList = new List<Bill_Of_Material__c>();
    listWrapper = new List<WrapperClass>();

    //--- Map of Bill of Material ---//           
    BOMMap = new  Map<Id,Bill_Of_Material__c>([SELECT Master_Material_Id__c, 
                                                      Issue_Quantity__c,
                                                      Job_Number__c,
                                                      Balance_Quantity_Required__c,
                                                      Quantity_In_Stock__c,
                                                      Total_Quantity_Required__c  
                                              FROM Bill_Of_Material__c 
                                              WHERE  Id =: CURRENT_BOM_ID]);
    for(Bill_Of_Material__c BOMLoop : BOMMap.values()) {
           BOMList.add(BOMLoop);
           RecordId.add(BOMLoop.Id);
           RecordId.add(BOMLoop.Master_Material_Id__c );
           RecordId.add(BOMLoop.Job_Number__c);
    }                                                                       

    //--- Map of Master Material ---//           
    MMMap = new Map<Id,Master_Material__c>([SELECT Material_Category__c,
                                              Quantity_BOI__c,
                                              Quantity_CASI__c,
                                              Quantity_RM__c 
                                            FROM Master_Material__c 
                                            WHERE Id =: RecordId]);

    //--- Map of Mater Material Line Item ---//
    MMLIMap = new Map<Id,Master_Material_LineItem__c>([SELECT Id,
                                                        Name,
                                                        PW_Material_ID__c,
                                                        Serial_Number__c,
                                                        Incoming_Date__c,
                                                        Total_Unit_Price__c,
                                                        Material_Category__c,
                                                        Total_Quantity__c 
                                                       FROM Master_Material_LineItem__c
                                                       WHERE PW_Material_ID__c =: RecordId 
                                                       AND Status__c =: STATUS_AVALIABLE]);

    if(MMLIMap.size() <= 0){
      ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.FATAL,'No Stock For Issuing The Materials'));
      hideButton_Issue=false;
    } 

    for(Master_Material__c MMMapLoop : MMMap.values()) {
      if(MMMapLoop.Material_Category__c == CONSUMABLE_AND_SAMLL_ITEM) {
        BOMMap.get(CURRENT_BOM_ID).Quantity_In_Stock__c = MMMapLoop .Quantity_CASI__c;
      }
      if(MMMapLoop.Material_Category__c == RAW_MATERIAL) {
        BOMMap.get(CURRENT_BOM_ID).Quantity_In_Stock__c = MMMapLoop .Quantity_RM__c;
      }
      if(MMMapLoop.Material_Category__c == BOUGHT_OUT_ITEM) { 
        BOMMap.get(CURRENT_BOM_ID).Quantity_In_Stock__c = MMMapLoop.Quantity_BOI__c;
      }   
    }                  

    //--- There are we Check if the stock is 0 show the error message ---//
    for(Master_Material_LineItem__c emp : MMLIMap.values()) {
      if(emp.Material_Category__c == CONSUMABLE_AND_SAMLL_ITEM) { 
        Count_CON_RAW++;
        if(Count_CON_RAW > 1) {
          ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.FATAL,'Please Contact Your System Admin,You Have More Then One Item'));
          hideButton_Issue = false;
        }
        else if(emp.Total_Quantity__c == 0) {
          ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.FATAL,'No Stock For Issuing The Materials'));
          hideButton_Issue = false;
        }
        else {
          listWrapper.add(new WrapperClass(emp));
          hideButton_Issue = true;
        }

      }
      else {
          listWrapper.add(new WrapperClass(emp));
          hideButton_Issue = true;
      }
    }
  } 

  //---  Wrapper class  ---// 
  public class WrapperClass {
    public Boolean checked {get;set;}
    public Master_Material_LineItem__c emp {get;set;}
    public WrapperClass(Master_Material_LineItem__c emp) {
      this.emp = emp;
    }
  }

  //--- This function is use for retun into the Job number ---//
  public PageReference ReturnPage() {
    return (new PageReference('/' + BOMMap.get(CURRENT_BOM_ID ).Job_Number__c));
  }

  //--- This is code for cancel button ---//
  public PageReference cancel() {
    return new PageReference('javascript:window.close()');
  }

   //--- In this code block we are put issue operation ---//
  public PageReference save() {
    diisplayPopup = true; 
    Integer I=0, count_for_consumable = 0, count_for_bought_out_item = 1;
    for(WrapperClass w : listWrapper) {
      if(w.checked) {
        RecordId_Checked.add(w.emp.id);
      }
    }       
    MMLIMap_Checkeds = new List<Master_Material_LineItem__c>([SELECT Id,
                                                                PW_Material_ID__c,
                                                                Total_Quantity__c 
                                                              FROM Master_Material_LineItem__c
                                                              WHERE Id =: RecordId_Checked]); 

    for(Master_Material_LineItem__c MMLIVar : MMLIMap_Checkeds) {
      if(MMLIMap_checked.containsKey(MMLIVar.Id)) {
        MMLIMap_checked.get(MMLIVar.Id).add(MMLIVar);
      }
      else {
        MMLIMap_checked.put(MMLIVar.Id, new List<Master_Material_LineItem__c>{MMLIVar});
      }
    }  

    for(WrapperClass w : listWrapper) {
      if(w.checked) { I++;          
        if(BOMMap.get(CURRENT_BOM_ID).Total_Quantity_Required__c >= I) {

          if(w.emp.Material_Category__c == CONSUMABLE_AND_SAMLL_ITEM) {
            massage = LOTS_MATERIAL_ISSUED_SUCCESSFULLY;
            if(BOMMap.get(CURRENT_BOM_ID ).Quantity_In_Stock__c > BOMMap.get(CURRENT_BOM_ID).Total_Quantity_Required__c) {
              count_for_consumable = Integer.valueOf(BOMMap.get(CURRENT_BOM_ID).Total_Quantity_Required__c);
            } 
            else {
              count_for_consumable = Integer.valueOf(BOMMap.get(CURRENT_BOM_ID).Quantity_In_Stock__c);
            }
            totalAmount = count_for_consumable;     
            InsertJMIList.add(CreateJMI(BOMMap.get(CURRENT_BOM_ID), w, count_for_consumable));
            for(Master_Material_LineItem__c MMLIVar : MMLIMap_checked.get(w.emp.id)) {
                MMLIVar.Total_Quantity__c -= count_for_consumable;
            }
            BOMMap.get(CURRENT_BOM_ID).Quantity_In_Stock__c         -= count_for_consumable;
            BOMMap.get(CURRENT_BOM_ID).Issue_Quantity__c            += count_for_consumable;
            BOMMap.get(CURRENT_BOM_ID).Balance_Quantity_Required__c -= count_for_consumable;
          }
          else {
            totalAmount = I;
            massage = NO_MATERIAL_ISSUED_SUCCESSFULLY;
            InsertJMIList.add(CreateJMI(BOMMap.get(CURRENT_BOM_ID), w, 1));
            for(Master_Material_LineItem__c MMLIVar : MMLIMap_checked.get(w.emp.id)) {
                MMLIVar.Job_Number__c = BOMMap.get(CURRENT_BOM_ID).Job_Number__c;
                MMLIVar.Status__c = STATUS_UNAVALIABLE;
            }
            BOMMap.get(CURRENT_BOM_ID).Quantity_In_Stock__c         -= count_for_bought_out_item;
            BOMMap.get(CURRENT_BOM_ID).Issue_Quantity__c            += count_for_bought_out_item;
            BOMMap.get(CURRENT_BOM_ID).Balance_Quantity_Required__c -= count_for_bought_out_item;
          }
        }
      } 
    }
    INSERT InsertJMIList;  
    UPDATE BOMMap.values();
    UPDATE MMLIMap_Checkeds; 
    return null; 
  } 

  /***** UTILITY METHODS FOR JOB MATERIAL ISSUE *****/ 
  public static New_Job_Material_Issued__c CreateJMI(Bill_Of_Material__c BOMRec, WrapperClass w, Integer Qty){
    New_Job_Material_Issued__c Job_MI   = new New_Job_Material_Issued__c();
    Job_MI.Quantity__c                  = Qty;
    Job_MI.Job_Number_Id__c             = BOMRec.Job_Number__c;
    Job_MI.BOM_Id__c                    = BOMRec.Id;
    Job_MI.Material_Name__c             = w.emp.PW_Material_ID__c;
    Job_MI.Material_Category__c         = w.emp.Material_Category__c ;
    Job_MI.Total_Unit_Price__c          = w.emp.Total_Unit_Price__c;
    Job_MI.Serial_Number__c             = w.emp.Serial_Number__c;
    Job_MI.Master_Material_Line_Item__c = w.emp.id;
    return Job_MI;
  }
}

  /***** UTILITY METHODS FOR BILL OF MATERIAL *****/
  /*
  Public static Bill_Of_Material__c BOMUPDATE(Integer qty){
   Bill_Of_Material__c BOMVarUPDATE = new Bill_Of_Material__c();
   BOMVarUPDATE.Quantity_In_Stock__c         -= qty;
   BOMVarUPDATE.Balance_Quantity_Required__c -= qty;
   BOMVarUPDATE.Issue_Quantity__c            += qty;
   return null;
  } */
```

and this is my test class

```
/**
 * Author :  Cloudiate Technology Limited
 * Description: Issue Material Handler 
 * Date: 12/01/2018
 */
@istest
Private class IssuedMaterialHandlerTestCases {    

        public class WrapperClass {
        public Boolean checked {get;set;}
        public Master_Material_LineItem__c emp {get;set;}
        public WrapperClass(Master_Material_LineItem__c emp) {
            this.emp = emp;
            this.checked = true;
        }
       }
       @istest static void first(){
            Master_Material__c mmVar = new Master_Material__c();                                
                  mmVar.Name                          = 'LI-100-900MM-REFLEX';
                  mmVar.Size_Capacity__c              = 'Lokesh';
                  mmVar.Make__c                       = 'Relience';
                  mmVar.Material_Category__c          = 'Consumables and Small items' ;
                  mmVar.Minimum_Inventory_Required__c = true;
                  mmVar.Minimum_Inventory_Level__c    = 5;
                  mmVar.Types__c                      = 'Batch';
                  mmVar.Lot_Size__c                   = 0;
                  mmVar.Issue_in_lots__c              = true;
                  mmVar.Material_Of_Construction__c   = 'Aamrpali';
                  mmVar.Material_Description__c       = 'Long Description';
                  mmVar.Issue_in_lots__c              = false;     
                  INSERT mmVar;     

            Account accVar = new Account();
                  accVar.Name = 'JSW Energy Ltd. Bellary';
                  INSERT accVar;

            Job_Number__c job = new Job_Number__c();
             job.Client_Name__c=accVar.Id;
             job.Project_Name__c='Anand Project';
             job.Description__c ='it is good';
             job.Capacity__c ='55';
             job.Input_Water_Type__c='Seawater';
             job.System_Type__c='Batch';
             job.Quantity_Of_Item__c='12';
             job.Location__c='Indore';
              INSERT job;

           Master_Material_LineItem__c mmliVar = new Master_Material_LineItem__c();
                 mmliVar.Job_Number__c                   =  job.Id;
                 mmliVar.PW_Material_ID__c               =  mmVar.Id ;
                 mmliVar.Material_Category__c            =  'Consumables and Small items'; 
                 mmliVar.Serial_Number__c                = '1243';
                // mmli.Incoming_Date__c                   =  date.today();
                 mmliVar.Total_Quantity__c                = 1243;
                 mmliVar.Status__c                       = 'Available';
                 mmliVar.Total_Unit_Price__c             = 12;
                 INSERT mmliVar;



            Bill_Of_Material__c bomVar = new Bill_Of_Material__c();
                  bomVar.Master_Material_Id__c      = mmVar.id;
                  bomVar.Total_Quantity_Required__c = 2;
                  bomVar.Quantity_In_Stock__c       = 2; 
                  bomVar.Stock_Status__c            = 'In_Stock';
                  bomVar.Job_Number__c              = job.Id;
                  INSERT bomVar;

                 List<Master_Material_LineItem__c> mmliList = [SELECT Id,
                                                        Name,
                                                        PW_Material_ID__c,
                                                        Serial_Number__c,
                                                        Incoming_Date__c,
                                                        Total_Unit_Price__c,
                                                        Material_Category__c,
                                                        Total_Quantity__c 
                                                       FROM Master_Material_LineItem__c
                                                       WHERE Id =: mmliVar.id ];

            list<WrapperClass> listWrapper= new  list<WrapperClass>();

            for(Master_Material_LineItem__c mmliWrapperVar : mmliList) {
               listWrapper.add(new WrapperClass(mmliWrapperVar));
            }     
           IssuedMaterialHandler.WrapperClass Wrapoli = new IssuedMaterialHandler.WrapperClass(mmliVar);
           ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.StandardController(bomVar);         
           IssuedMaterialHandler bomObj = new IssuedMaterialHandler(sc);   
           bomObj.save();
         //  bomObj.ReturnPage();
           bomObj.cancel();
        }
}
```

i am not able to cover this part

```
 for(Bill_Of_Material__c BOMLoop : BOMMap.values()) {
           BOMList.add(BOMLoop);
           RecordId.add(BOMLoop.Id);
           RecordId.add(BOMLoop.Master_Material_Id__c );
           RecordId.add(BOMLoop.Job_Number__c);
    }
```

Can you please help me

Answer (score 4):

Your test class is not performing any tests, because you do not `assert` anything about the behavior of your class. This is commonly called a "smoke test" because it does nothing save establishing in a restricted set of circumstances that your code does not crash. It is a common but very poor practice in Salesforce.

In this case, however, you can simply eliminate the loop and the `Map<Id, Bill_Of_Material__c>`. Since you are using a query with an `Id` filter, you will always get back either one or zero results. You can query into a `List` and simply check whether or not the list is empty.

That fact that you don't already have coverage of this code points to a bug: your `CURRENT_BOM_ID` variable is declared `static` and populated from `ApexPages.CurrentPage`. It should be a non-static instance variable. You can get this value from your standard controller, which you populate in the test class, by doing `controller.getRecord()`, checking to see if it is `null`, and using its Id.